# Facebook share not working on mobile ("Can't load:url")

Tags: facebook-sharer, facebook-share

I have a weird problem, with the most simplistic FB share button. It works well on a laptop, but not mobile. On mobile you get the "Can't Load Url; The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains....blah"

First of all, I didn't even know you actually need a separate app for the simple share button. But I created that. No changes. Searching the internet, someone says that it might help to add m2w to sharer.php? But that didn't do anything either. Here's a [sample url](http://www.triparound.org/user/siim/66), just press the Share button on mobile. And you can check, on your computer it works without issues.

Thanks in advance.

PS: I just noticed an `app_id` mismatch, after I fixed that, pressing the FB share button simply keeps on loading. So the problem still exists.

Comment: Did you solved it? I'm having the same issue.